# ¿Listar métodos en Visual Studio Code 2019?

Tags: vscode

Estoy trabajando con *Visual Studio Code 2019* en Ubuntu / Windows.
¿Hay un atajo de teclado o algún comando para listar todos los métodos o funciones del fichero actual?

Comment: Prueba con `workbench.action.gotoSymbol`(CTRL+Shift+O por defecto). Otra opción sería el [outline view](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_outline-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- El comando es workbench.action.gotoSymbol
- El atajo de teclado por defecto: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- Para agrupar todas las funciones/métodos por tipo, presiona `:`
  después del atajo de teclado.

Esta pregunta de SO tiene también información sobre lenguajes en que el comando funciona y cómo hacer que funcione en los que no: [Method List in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154283/method-list-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Funciona la combinación `CTRL+Shift+O` donde la tecla final es la letra O, no un cero. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Gracias a tí! :-) He intentado editar la respuesta para asegurarme de que no es un cero, pero parece correcto (una o). Lo has corregido tú o es que no se vé claro en pantalla?

Comment: El eterno dilema si es un 0 o una O: `0 !== O`